# Fix hash positions in hash

Tags: perl

I have the following code which passes data to a csv, however the column order in the CSV is seemingly random (I pass a hash to the CSV). I'm having real difficulty defining the order of the columns.

Is there a way I can fix the position of hashes in my %output_var hash so I can effectively define the column order in my CSV?

```
$common->print_header('text/csv','export_order_products.csv');
print common::to_csv(sort values %output_var)."\r\n";
my $cart_id;
foreach my $order (@data_to_export) {
  $order->{'order-id'} =~ s/\.cgi//;
  $order->{'order-item-id'} =~ s/\.cgi//;
  $order->{'purchase-date'} =~ s/\.cgi//;
  my @line;
  for (sort {$output_var{$a} cmp $output_var{$b}; } keys %output_var) {
    push @line, $order->{$_};
  }
   print common::to_csv(@line)."\r\n";
                }
```

CSV sub:

```
sub to_csv {
    my ($csv_line);
    my (@fields) = @_;
    my $i;
    for ($i=0; $i<scalar(@fields); $i++) {
        $fields[$i] =~ s/\r/\\r/gis;
        $fields[$i] =~ s/\n/\\n/gis;
        $fields[$i] =~ s/"/""/gis; # -- "
        $fields[$i] =~ s/(.*,.*)/"$1"/gis;
        $fields[$i] = '' if ($fields[$i] eq '0');
    }
    $csv_line = join ',', @fields;
    return $csv_line;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're were using Text::CSV or Text::CSV_XS,

```
# Outside the loop
$csv->column_names([qw( ... )]);

# Inside the loop
$csv->print_hr($fh, $order);
```

But you don't appear to be using either of those modules(?!?!), so

```
# Outside the loop
my @headers = qw( ... );

# Inside the loop
print($fh to_csv(@$order{@headers}), "\r\n");
```

Comment: This is really cool. To find out more about how/why this works, google "perl hash slice". Note the syntax `@$order{@headers}`. You might think you could also do something like this, but you cannot. `$order->{@headers}`

Comment: @Mort, However, you can do [`$order->@{@headers}`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408) since 5.24 (or since 5.20 if you use `use feature qw( postderef );` and `no warnings qw( experimental::postderef );`);